# Telerik MVC DetailView binding issue - Master Details

Tags: asp.net, telerik-mvc

I am getting below error at .DetailView line. How do I bind the detailview grid?

> the best overloaded method match for
>   Telerik.web.mvc.ui.fluent.GridDetailsViewBuilder.ClientTemplate(string)
>   has some invalid arguments

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<Models.Employee>()
        .Name("GridView1")
        .BindTo(Model)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.EmpId).Width(100);
        })
         .DetailView(detailView => detailView.ClientTemplate(
                        Html.Telerik().Grid<Models.Employee>()
                             .Name("<#= EmpID #>")
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception describes the **ClientTemplate** method expects a string. You can call the **ToHtmlString**() extension method at the end of the child Grid declaration.

Just like highlighted in this demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchyajax